# Can we deduce that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $detA_{n}=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence, determinant

Let $δ_{n},θ_{n},ω_{n}$ be three real sequences converging to $δ,θ,ω$ respectively. Define the following matrix

$$A_{n} = \begin{bmatrix}
δ_{n-1} & θ_{n-1} & ω_{n-1} \\
δ_{n} & θ_{n} & ω_{n} \\
δ_{n+1} & θ_{n+1} & ω_{n+1} \end{bmatrix}$$

Assume that $detA_{n}=0$ for some integers $n$ but there is no method to see that this determinant is zero infinitely many times. Since the sequences are convergent, we get $$lim_{n→∞}A_{n}=A=\begin{bmatrix}
δ & θ & ω \\
δ & θ & ω \\
δ & θ & ω \end{bmatrix}$$

and we get $detA=0$ by some relations between $δ,θ,ω$.

My **question** is: Based on this last result can we deduce that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $detA_{n}=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Perhaps the first $20$ terms of each sequence is zero.
From then on, say $\delta_n=\exp(-2n)$, $\theta_n=\exp(-n)$ and $\omega_n=2$.  The determinant is never zero again.